# Pass user's entry to one of two overloaded methods and display a return string

Tags: c#, user-input, overloading

I am currently working on a program exercise for school. I am to create a program that allows the user to enter an integer item number or a string description. Then the entry is passed to one of two overloaded `GetDetails()` methods, and then display a returned string with all the order details.

If the method version accepts the integer it looks up the description and price.

If the method version accepts the string description it looks up the item number and price.

The methods return an appropriate message if the item is not found.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string inputstring;
        int itemNum;

        WriteLine("Enter the item number or description of the item you would like to order.");
        inputstring = ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(inputstring, out itemNum);
        GetDetails(itemNum);
    }

    private static void GetDetails(string itemNum)
    {           
        if (itemNum == "Enchilada")
            WriteLine("Item number 20 priced at $2.95.");
        else if (itemNum == "Burrito")
            WriteLine("Item number 23 priced at $1.95.");
        else if (itemNum == "Taco")
            WriteLine("Item number 25 priced at $2.25.");
        else if (itemNum == "Tostada")
            WriteLine("Item number 31 priced at $3.10.");
        else
            WriteLine("Item not found.");
    }

    private static void GetDetails(int itemNum)
    {            
        if (itemNum == 20)
            WriteLine("The Enchilada is priced at $2.95.");
        else if (itemNum == 23)
            WriteLine("The Burrito is priced at $1.95.");
        else if (itemNum == 25)
            WriteLine("The Taco is priced at $2.25.");
        else if (itemNum == 31)
            WriteLine("The Tostada is priced at $3.10.");
        else
            WriteLine("Item not found.");
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is getting the string side of this to work. which I can do by removing `int.TryParse(inputstring, out itemNum);` and changing the `GetDetails(inputstring)`. This will allow the string to work but won't let the item number side of the program to work. I am starting to feel extremely overwhelmed trying to get this to work and would love some input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int.TryParse(inputstring, out itemNum);
GetDetails(itemNum);
```

to

```
if (int.TryParse(inputstring, out itemNum)) 
{
    GetDetails(itemNum);
}
else
{
    GetDetails(inputstring);
}
```

If `TryParse` is successful it returns `true`. This will then use the `int` version of the method. Otherwise, if the input cannot be parsed to an `int`, then the `string` method is used.

Comment: Wow after seeing this things make so much more sense now. Thank you very much. I had to fix some other things in the code but this is what I needed to get me the break through I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help!